# Solution of differential equation (Dirac delta function)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, differential-equations, dirac-delta-distributions

I have been given the following:

$$y''(x)+\omega^2y(x)=s(x),$$

$$s(x)= \delta(x)-\delta\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$   for $-\frac{1}{4}<x<\frac{3}{4}$. 
 (Periodically repeating for $x$ outside this interval.)

Question:
Find the Fourier series solution y(x) of the above differential equation.

I understand how to compute the Fourier series of a function. I understand how to solve a second order differential equation. However, combining the topics is proving difficult.

I have assumed a solution:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}y_{n}e^{2\pi{inx}}$$
My problem occurs when I attempt to find the fourier series of $s(x)$. I think the coefficients can be written: $$ a_0=2\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \left[\delta (x) - \delta \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] \,dx$$
 $$ a_n=2\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \left[\delta (x) - \delta \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] \cos(n \pi x)\,dx$$
$$ b_n=2\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \left[\delta (x) - \delta \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] \sin(n \pi x) \,dx$$
But I do not know how I go about computing these. If it weren't the dirac delta function, I would know what I am doing. So i guess I am also asking for some intuition behind the dirac delta 'function'.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: quasi duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2545100/160660

Answer (score 0):

The delta function has the defining property that

$$\int_{-a}^{a}\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$$

In other words, as long as the domain of integration contains the point where the argument of the $\delta$ is zero, the $\delta$ just pulls out the rest of the integrand evaluated at that point.

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: ok, this makes sense for $a_n$ and $b_n$ because the sin and cos are the functions. Does this mean that $a_0$ would just go to zero?

Comment: It would appear so

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I got an answer in the end (that seems reasonable) :D